# Oracle SQL automated reports

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, reporting

I teached myself how to use Oracle SQL using Oracle SQL developer and in the right now I am able to generate some very useful overviews for my manager (as a separate task from my normal job). However, I always have to use Oracle SQL developer to get these overviews and then I have to export them to PDF/XLSX manually.

I am wondering if there is any possibility to generate these reports automatically and get a PDF/XLSX containing all information in you email or a specified folder. I tried some external software, but no succes.

Comment: I think you'd have to consider coding this in a programming language like Java, C#, dealer's choice...  I've seen it done where a SQL report is run and formatted in an email but if you want to spit it out in a PDF/XLSX it'd be more complicated.

Comment: I don't think that exact set of features is available just yet. The comment thread on [this blog article by @thatjeffsmith](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/03/how-to-share-reports/) has some hints on how to do things. There are no links in the thread, you'll need to poke around Jeff's blog to find the articles he alludes to.

Comment: hi, in Sqlplus we can get CSV output or HTML output , try using Sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

in Sqlplus we can get CSV output or HTML output , try using Sqlplus

```
SQL>
SQL>set markup html on spool on 
SQL>SPOOL /tmp/xyz.HTML 
SQL>set pagesize 200 
SQL>set echo on 
SQL> select * from myTable; 
SQL>spool off 
SQL> set markup html off spool off
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enouh privileges to create view, you can compile one with statement of your query and link via ODBC with Excel file.